# WooCommerce add shortcode to product attributes

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to add content to a product attribute.
This would mean that the value of a attribute can contain a shortcode.

The problem is that the shortcode itself is shown.

Here is what I did:

```
function prepare_temp( $atts ){
    echo 'something';
}
add_shortcode( 'degrees', 'prepare_temp' );
```

This creates a shortcode but if I place this in the attribute value field it just shows `[degrees]`

Any way I can fix this by showing: `something`?

Comment: where is your action

Comment: Euhm... Assuming from your reaction it's missing but when I use it anywhere else it works and shows me what I want to see. However I can add one and see if it helps... Thnx

Comment: Should there be an action? https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: do you think you are going in right direction ?? if you want to run this code then only remove $atts from function but if you want to configer with wocommerce then use action

Comment: Yes I do think that I'm going in the right direction but judging from your answer I don't however would and action like this be right? `add_action( 'init', 'prepare_temp' );`

Comment: So you would like to pass a kind of variable value to something that will be a post field in admin product pages. Is it a custom field or an existing field?

Comment: It's an custom field? I guess. It uses the default "custom attribute panel"